# Are these header details being written properly?

Tags: c++

I have a header file called calendarType.h

Is it appropriate to add

```
#ifndef calendarType
#define calendarType
```

**and**

```
#endif as the last row?
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, those will work to make sure the lines in between `#ifdef` and `#endif` are only parsed once during each compilation (even if they get `#include`'d from more than one location)

The only thing I might do differently is to change `calendarType` to `calendarType_h` in each of the first two lines -- that will help make sure the `#define`'d macro-token doesn't interfere with any class or struct named `calendarType`.

Comment: does endif have to have anything after it

Comment: like the name of the file again, or can I just say :#endif

Comment: No, nothing goes after the `#endif`

Answer (score 1):

Those are called *include guards*. They should be used in most header files to avoid a problem known as *double inclusion*. Double inclusion will most likely result in failed compilation. From Wikipedia:

> If certain C or C++ language constructs are defined twice, the resulting translation unit is invalid.

`#pragma once` is an alternative to traditional *include guards*. While not actually part of the C++ standard, it is well supported across compilers. `#pragma once` is less code to type and less prone to error (e.g. accidentally re-using the same include guard).